# What algorithm Asp.net Identity uses to encrypt the password?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, algorithm, encryption, asp.net-identity-2

What kind of algorithm does `Asp.Net Identity` framework use to encrypt the password? I have a scenario where android, iPhone, web and desktop use the same database.
This password should be encrypted, so in `ASP.NET MVC` I have used Identity framework to encrypt the password. Now I need the algorithm to work for all platforms.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: MD5 for Hashing and SHA1 for Encryption.

Comment: This question is too broad, ASP.NET as a framework contains implementations of a lot of crypto algorithms, but the usage of the specific cipher, mac of KDF is defined on the level of the specific product.

Comment: @OlegEstekhin http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.hmacsha1(v=vs.110).aspx

FYIP For SHA1 encryption.

Comment: @ArijitMukherjee this link both not relevant for the question and also it points to something which is not simply "SHA1" and which is absolutely not an encryption algorithm.

Comment: @OlegEstekhin While it might be too broad for ASP.NET, the question is specifically about [ASP.NET Identity](http://aspnetidentity.codeplex.com/).

Comment: The way password is hashed on the server should not be a concern for all your clients. So whatever hashing is used by Identity framework, should be good enough for your clients.

Answer (score 20):

ASP.NET Identity uses [Password-Based Key Derivation Function 2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2) (PBKDF2) as implemented by [`Rfc2898DeriveBytes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rfc2898derivebytes(v=vs.110).aspx). It is a hashing algorithm.

Note that [encryption and hashing are different](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4948322/fundamental-difference-between-hashing-and-encryption-algorithms).

```
public static string HashPassword(string password)
{
    byte[] salt;
    byte[] bytes;
    if (password == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("password");
    }
    using (Rfc2898DeriveBytes rfc2898DeriveByte = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, 16, 1000))
    {
        salt = rfc2898DeriveByte.Salt;
        bytes = rfc2898DeriveByte.GetBytes(32);
    }
    byte[] numArray = new byte[49];
    Buffer.BlockCopy(salt, 0, numArray, 1, 16);
    Buffer.BlockCopy(bytes, 0, numArray, 17, 32);
    return Convert.ToBase64String(numArray);
}
```

Comment: Encryption technique is indeed SHA1 check the msdn reference you have provided.

Comment: As far as I understand, the use of SHA1 is only one part of the process, which is to use *a pseudo-random number generator based on HMACSHA1*.

Comment: yes that's what OP asked for which encryption technique and not the Hashing using teh Salt etc.

Comment: Possibly. Knowing that the hashing algorithm used is SHA1 couldn't possibly be very helpful to anyone though. You need to know how the password is hashed. SHA1 is just an implementation detail of `Rfc2898DeriveBytes`.

Comment: Also, SHA1 **is** a hashing algorithm, **not** an encryption technique.

Comment: Please check and answer for the following question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40012839/is-asp-net-identity-hashing-secured

Answer (score 1):

This depends on the selected compatibility mode.

Implementation details can be found in their [Github repo](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/52eff90fbcfca39b7eb58baad597df6a99a542b0/src/Identity/Extensions.Core/src/PasswordHasher.cs#L23)

At this moment they support:

version 2

- PBKDF2 with HMAC-SHA1, 128-bit salt, 256-bit subkey, 1000 iterations
- Format: { 0x00, salt, subkey }

version 3

- PBKDF2 with HMAC-SHA256, 128-bit salt, 256-bit subkey,
  10000 iterations.
- Format: { 0x01, prf (UInt32), iter count (UInt32), salt length (UInt32), salt, subkey }  (All UInt32s are stored big-endian.)